# How show chrome bookmarks bar on custom newtab page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, bookmarks

I have one problem.
I build chrome extension and override the newtab page with my custom page.
Bookmarks bar display on default Chrome newtab page, but hide on my custom new tab page.

[image: Default Chrome Bookmarks Bar]

Maybe, anyone have some idea: how display Bookmarks bar WITH CHROME API?
Please, skip tips such as press key combination Ctrl+Shift+B or make your own   Bookmarks bar page, only chrome api interest me.

Comment: Perhaps the (oddly named) [chrome.bookmarks api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks)

Answer (score 9):

Sorry. It is not possible for now.

Chromium doesn't have that kind of API.

chrome.bookmarks API is for adding, removing, getting bookmarks.

Comment: Although one could probably implement their own version by getting the bookmarks and displaying them.

Comment: @abraham that approach though face some limitation as the native bookmarks bar has the ability to unroll sub-menus outside of the chrome window