# How to keep show out Bookmark, Display Google App list, Google accout icon in new tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working make a chrome extension to overwrite new tab.

```
"chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "index.html"
},
```

Every thing working fine, but, I got some issues:

1. By default, Bookmark Bar always hidden, just show out when open new tab (New tab default GG chrome). But when I use my extension, Bookmark bar doesn't show out when I open a new tab. Has any way to make my extension can display Bookmark bar like default?
2. Quick navigation (I'm not sure I call right name) on new tab
   [image: Quick navigation]

Has anyway to keep this section on my new-tab extension?

Thank for your readding!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How show chrome bookmarks bar on custom newtab page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714939/how-show-chrome-bookmarks-bar-on-custom-newtab-page)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714939/how-show-chrome-bookmarks-bar-on-custom-newtab-page), it is not yet possible. If you think this can improve the extension development experience, make sure an appropriate request is [filed in the issue tracker](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/faq#faq-fea-02).